# How PARTITIONED BY works?

Tags: hive

I have created below table, want to understand how the partition works, the partition column `LogDate` is not part of table DDL so how the partition works and how the data distribution & retrieval happens.

```
create table tbl_1
(
CollectTimeStamp TIMESTAMP,
ObjectColumnName VARCHAR(256),
ObjectDatabaseName           VARCHAR(256),
TypeofUse                    TINYINT
)
PARTITIONED BY (LogDate STRING)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\u0001'
stored as ORC
LOCATION '/tables/db1/tbl_1' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The partition column ``definitely IS a part of table DDL, because `PARTITIONED BY` IS also DDL. 
Partition is a folder, so it's not necessary to store partition key data in data files. 
Partition information (partition key, location) is stored in the metastore database. Partition column should be last in the insert overwrite sentence for dynamic partition load. 
When you query table, hive reads information about partitions (keys, locations) from the metastore. 
Location (folder) can be attached as a partition:

```
ALTER TABLE page_view ADD PARTITION (dt='2008-08-08', country='us') location '/path/to/us/part080808'
```

See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL